# Azure Data Factory - When enabled git n azure Data factory the Trigger Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am not able to schedule a event trigger automatically when Git is enabled in azure data factory.
Manual trigger is working and the automatic trigger wouldn't work and not appear in monitor tab.

[image]

Comment: What trigger are you referring to? Please edit your question for clarity. I'm not sure what issue you're experiencing, based on current description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the changes for the event trigger to be activated. I just tested without publishing and uploading file into blob, trigger did not work. After publishing, it worked. Option is as shown below.

[image]